# Cannot convert value of type 'Timer' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?' Swift 5

Tags: swift5, nstimer

I am facing an issue while adding `Timer` inside the completion block of the present alert controller.

**Error:** `Cannot convert value of type 'Timer' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'`

```
func showAutoHideAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Please help how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: So you want the alert to dismiss automatically after 3 seconds? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper, I want to dismiss UIAlertController to dismiss after 3 seconds.